# Print the node author's full name on a custom node template

Tags: 7, theming, configuration

I have a content type "Blog entry" which I have overridden the template. (node--blog_entry.tpl.php)

The target is to display the node author's full name (as a link) which will take the user to a page (produced by a view) which shows all the other articles they have written.

In my template file, I have the following code:

```
 function bootstrap_mysite_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
   $vars['author_name'] = $vars['name'];
   $vars['submitted_dt'] = format_date($vars['node']->created, 'custom', 'jS F Y');
 }
```

The view that I have created which shows the author's other articles takes the UserID as an argument, so what I need is to display a link which which shows the author's full name, but passes their UserID.

the code I have in my custom content template is:

```
<div class="author-name">
    WRITTEN BY <a href="/user-posts/<?php print $uid; ?>"> <?php print $author_name; ?></a>
  </div>
```

But author name is not only the author's username (not their full name) but it is output as a link which is no good for me.  I simply want to output the author's full name as plain text.

So, to summarise - 
What can I use instead of `$vars['name']; (which produces`a username that links to a profile)
that will instead produce some plain text of the user's full name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't indicate whether you are storing the user's full name anywhere. You can add fields to the user profile (at `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`). Suppose you add a firstname field (field_user_fname) and lastname field (field_user_lname), you could then write a custom function in your template file, like this:

```
function _get_author_name($uid) {
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $uid);
  $fname = $wrapper->field_user_fname->value();
  $lname = $wrapper->field_user_lname->value();
  return "$fname $lname";
}
```

And then, since you already know the UID, you could call the function from your content template:

```
<div class="author-name">
    WRITTEN BY <a href="/user-posts/<?php print $uid; ?>"> 
    <?php print _get_author_name($uid); ?></a>
  </div>
```

You could also investigate the [Realname module.](https://www.drupal.org/project/realname)

Answer (score 0):

Update the nme variable by fetching the admin/config/people/accounts/fields  first_name and last_name (if existing or else add and use same machine name in below code snippet)

```
use Drupal\Core\Session\AnonymousUserSession;

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_username() for username.html.twig.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_username(&$variables) {
  $account = $variables['account'] ?: new AnonymousUserSession();

  $variables['extra'] = '';
  $variables['uid'] = $account->id();
  if (empty($variables['uid'])) {
    if (theme_get_setting('features.comment_user_verification')) {
      $variables['extra'] = ' (' . t('Anonymous') . ')';
    }
  }


 // that $variables['name'] is safe for printing.
 // Use machine name of Fields First Name and Last Name
 $name = $account->get('first_name')->value.' '.$account->get('last_name')->value;

 if (mb_strlen($name) > 20) {
    $name = Unicode::truncate($name, 15, FALSE, TRUE);
 }

  $variables['name'] = $name;
  // {{ username }} and {{extra}} will be available within username.html.twig.
}
```